# How do i stop the form validation code from repeating when i click the submit button (php ajax jquery html)

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Hey all i'm new to working with ajax but i am trying to make some form validation and its going well except for this code repeating itself.

This is what happens after clicking the submit button twice... and if i keep pressing submit it keeps repeating. I only need it to show once no matter how many times the submit button is pressed.

Much appreciated to anyone who could give me a hint on how to stop this code repeating!! Thanks!

[image: This is what happens after clicking the submit button twice]

The forms action calls this php file:

```
$errors = [];
$data = [];


// change the $error message for each field here
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors['name'] = '<div class="my-3 alert alert-danger";>Please enter a valid name.</div>';
} else if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors['name'] = '<div class="my-3 alert alert-success";>Name Entered.</div>';
}

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors['email'] = '<p class="my-3 alert alert-danger";>Please enter a valid email address.</p>';
} else if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors['email'] = '';
}

if (empty($_POST['comment'])) {
    $errors['comment'] = '<p class="my-3 alert alert-danger";>Please leave a comment.</p>';
} else if (!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
    $errors['comment'] = '';
}

// if the fields are not empty then return successful
if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Your Request Has Been Successful! <a class="text-success" href="./">Click here to continue.</a>';
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

I also have this form.js file linked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    var formData = {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      comment: $("#comment").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./php/process.php",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    })
      .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        if (!data.success) {
          if (data.errors.name) {
            $("#name-group").addClass("has-error");
            $("#name-group").append(
              '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + "</div>"
            );
          }

          if (data.errors.email) {
            $("#email-group").addClass("has-error");
            $("#email-group").append(
              '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + "</div>"
            );
          }

          if (data.errors.comment) {
            $("#comment-group").addClass("has-error");
            $("#comment-group").append(
              '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.comment + "</div>"
            );
          }
        } else {
          $("form").html(
            '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>"
          );
        }
      })

      .fail(function (data) {
        $("form").html(
          '<div class="alert alert-danger">Could not reach server, please try again <a href="./test-form" >here</a>.</div>'
        );
      });

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

And finally the form itself:

```
            <form action="./php/process.php" method="POST">
                <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"
                        onchange="myFunction()" />
                </div>

                <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                        placeholder="email@example.com" onchange="myFunction()" />
                </div>

                <div id="comment-group" class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Leave a comment:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment"
                        placeholder="Leave a comment" onchange="myFunction()" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    Submit
                </button>

            </form>
```

Comment: `.append()` adds more HTML to the element. If you want to ovewrite it, use `.html()`

Comment: @ADyson this doesn't work because when i change append() to html() the alerts show but the input fields disappear.

Comment: You need to have another div inside that then, and write the errors to there.